# Double (32- and 64-bit) Windows Installation on the Same PC

Tags: windows, multi-boot, license

I have a 32-bit Windows 10 Professional installation (upgrade from 8.0 and 8.1) on an old PC. The Windows license is RETAIL channel and the License Status: Licensed. Due to the 32-bit limitations I wish to upgrade the installation to 64-bit. I know such an upgrade is not possible, so I need to make a new 64-bit installation. The installation will be on a new disk.

I have a lot of applications and data on the 32-bit installation and reinstalling and transferring them could take a month or so. Therefore it would be very helpful if I could have both installations **<strike>running</strike>** available for some time.

I have a few questions:

- As far as I know license types concern the Home, Professional or Server editions, but not the 32/64-bit configuration. Am I right?
- Is it legal to make this upgrade?
- Is it OK to have both installations running at the same time? They will be both on the same machine, of course. I know Microsoft associates the installation key to the board S/N, however they must be keeping more data, which they update after a hardware upgrade, a CPU upgrade for example. So would this be acceptable, or it will mess up my account management or (their) bookkeeping?

And one technical question, is it possible to have the two versions installed on separate disks, and choose which one to run every time? Would it be best to make a dual-boot configuration or instead use the BIOS settings to specify the boot device? I want the 64-bit installation to have the boot drive mapped as C:, and of course uninstall the 32-bit one at some point.

Thank you in advance

---

**EDIT:**

I do not need to have both installations running simultaneously, just be able to boot and choose either of the two. Applications will need to be reinstalled anyway, while the data can be copied to a network location to be transferred. Isn't it possible to have two Windows installations on the same machine? So a dual-boot installation basically, the only difference being that both instllations will be using the same key. Is this possible, or I should instead get a new key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Therefore it would be very helpful if I could have both installations
> running for some time.

**(A) Dual Boot:**

You cannot do this Dual Boot (only one system on at a time).

However you can use Dual Boot to start up the new system and start working on it and use the other system as long as you need to. You can do this with one Retail license of Windows.

**(B) Physical to Virtual P2V approach:**

The other very practical way is via Virtual Machine on the current system, which will work.

It could be problematic if your VM is the 64-bit system that you want.

With VMware Workstation and VMware Converter, you can P2V the 32-bit system. That makes a VM of the existing system. This would be the preferred approach.

This needs a good strong machine with a large fast SSD Drive.

Now format, install Windows 10 64-bit and VMware Workstation. Load up the 32-bit guest and start moving software and data over.

This provides the value of running both machines (one virtual) at the same time on the same machine. I have done this.

> I have a lot of applications and data on the 32-bit installation and
> reinstalling and transferring them could take a month or so.

To be very honest, since I have done this, the worst case is two days to have a basic system running, Office, Adobe, and all data. Since data includes my software files, I can do this as I work and within 3 or 4 days it is all done.

However you can do it the VMware method I have laid out. This will work.

**(C) New Computer:**

You could elect to get a new, strong, future oriented computer (able to run Windows 11 down the road should you wish to).

Then you can put the two Windows 10 computers beside each other and network them. Start setting up the new computer and pick your point when you transition to the new.

The value of this approach is the computer you want (64-bit) good for the next 5 or 6 years.

Comment: I would use Oracle VirtualBox, and create a vhdx that mounts directly to the old harddisk. Install the 64 bit first, Oracle VM in there and mount the old harddisk through the vhdx. This allows you to go back to the old install but work mostly on the new one. A 64bit VM cannot be run on a 32bit os anyway, but the other way around is possible. It is of course also possible to just swap harddisks, which may be the easiest and best way to make the switch as fast as possible.

Comment: @ John and @LPChip, Thank you for your answers! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I have rephrased my question a little, could you please take another look?

Comment: @John, Unfortunately there is a lot of stuff on that machine, database servers, application servers, development tools and a multitude of third-party utilities and tools. Actually this is the main reason I wish to upgrade, ie to overcome the 4GB limitation, it can't run all these efficiently. It can indeed take a lot of time to reinstall, configure and iron-out everyhting, although I'm not going to install all these on the same machine again. Plus this isn't the only job I have to do, I'm busy doing normal work.

Comment: You can Dual Boot two retail systems - That should not be an issue. I did lay out Dual Boot in my Answer. That seems somewhat inconvenient to me, but it will definitely work - just a bit slower. I did amplify that section in my Answer that dual boot will work

Comment: I edited my answer to systematically provide 3 workable approaches for you. All will work and all have their pros and cons.

Comment: This is what I needed to know. Thank you!